# Переполнение буфера в стеке. Компилятор

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int check_authentication(char *pas)
{
    char pas_buffer[16];
    int auth_flag = 0;

    strcpy(pas_buffer, pas);

    if(strcmp(pas_buffer, "brillig") == 0)
        auth_flag = 1;
    if(strcmp(pas_buffer, "outgrabe") == 0)
        auth_flag = 1;

    return auth_flag;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s <password>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }
    if(check_authentication(argv[1]))
            printf("Access Granted\n");
    else
        printf("Access Denied\n");

    return 0;
}
```

При переполнении буфера программы, в переменную auth_flag заноситсся ненулевое значение, из-за чего получаем "Access Granted". Но ведь переменная auth_flag должно добавляться в стек после массивка pas_buffer. Т.е. значение переменной auth_flag должно оставаться равным 0

Изучаю переполнение буфера. Но столкнулся с такой проблемой, что переменные в стеке хранятся в неправильном порядке. Узнал, что компилятор может менять порядок переменных в стеке(для оптимизации или чего-то еще). Можно как-нибудь сделать так, чтобы компилятор(gcc) ничего не изменял? Или посоветуйте другой компилятор

Comment: *"Но ведь переменная auth_flag должно добавляться в стек после массивка pas_buffer."* - ничего подобного. Также не следует полагать, что переменные с автоматическим временем хранения обязательно хранятся на стеке.

Comment: *"Никто ничего никому не обещал"* :) Сикорда читаете?

Comment: компилятор спокойно может выбросить эту переменную  (что, к примеру, большинство и делает уже на -O1

Comment: Выходы за пределы массива ведёт только к **неопределённому** поведению программы. Вам нужно выбрать другой путь. Например, проследить вручную длину строки аргумента.

Comment: @AlexGlebe неопределенное поведение - это значит только то, что конкретное поведение не определено стандартом, но у конкретного экзешника в любом случае будет конкретное поведение, и это поведение можно определить опытным путем или дизассемблировав этот экзешник. Т.е. наличие неопределенного поведения не значит, что нужно искать какой-то другой путь)

Comment: Как можно посоветовать, чтобы компилятор работал **нестандартно** таким путём, чтобы **автору** вопроса было удобно? @insolor Это в том-же духе: какую сковородку посоветуете, чтобы яйца не сгорали?

Comment: думаю, что автору нужно просто взять какой-то старый компилятор, который не сильно оптимизировал код и на нем экспериментировать. Под словом старый я имею ввиду visual studio 6  или Borland c++ 5 (не билдер). С++ билдер не рекомендую, там код такой получается, что ужас.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, никак. Но на практике и нет никакого выбора, есть только исполняемый файл с возможными уязвимостями, и с конкретным поведением (не неопределенным).